# angularjs 1.x modifying data attribute with

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using an html theme that uses jQuery plugins. For example:

```
<div class="slide background-overlay-dark" data-parallax-image="images/parallax/4.jpg">
</div>
```

How would I be able to modify the data-parallax-image="" from the controller, without writing a directive, since there are many such cases.

Comment: You don't...use a directive. A directive exposes each element and assures it exists before the plugin code is run

Comment: Would you mind then just give a few lines code of how I would do this for this example?

Comment: Numerous examples around for integrating a jQuery plugin into a directive. Both on this site and other parts of web

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using plain javascript if you want to. The implementation for the same would be something like this.

Give your div an id, like `id="div1"` in my case.

**html code**

```
<div id="div1" class="slide background-overlay-dark" data-parallax-image="images/parallax/4.jpg"></div>
```

Now in your controller write a javascript function which updates the `data-parallax-image` attribute.

**Controller**

```
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
function changeImage() {
    var imageName = "something-"+Date.now();
    element.setAttribute('data-parallax-image', imageName);
}
setInterval(function() {
    changeImage();
}, 1000);
```

The `changeImage` function would modify the `data-parallax-image`from your controller without making a directive. In the given code I am running the changeImage() in an interval of one second. This logic purely depends on you and you can write it accordingly.